# Cache in Java web application

Tags: java, ehcache

I have question here regarding the cache technique in java web applications.

Suppose If i implement the ehcache, where the cached data will be stored?

will the cached data comes under GC covered area? i mean will GC deletes the java objects which i cached earlier?

after reading some cached framework sites, i understood that at core level they(caching framework) are using the hastable or hashmap, where data will be our value and key be depending on logic.

Suppose in ehcache 
       maxBytesLocalHeap="50m"
       maxBytesLocalDisk="50G"
1. what i understood here is 50Mb(maxBytesLocalHeap) will be stored in heap memory(the data which comes under this memory will be observed by GC),
2. If maxBytesLocalDisk 50GB will stored in the local disk (assuming file will be stored as a flat file in temp folder of the server) where GC will not care about the entities or objects as it is out of heap memory.

Is my understanding is correct?

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GC will delete your objects only if any other objects don't have references at it. GC doesn't know where your cached data it just looks for alone objects.

Yes, HashMap is commonly used to store cached data and retrieve it when needed.